# VideoCapture error OpenCV 3.0.0 in Visual Studio 2013 in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-2013, linker-errors, video-capture

I am working on an OpenCV 3.0.0 32-bit Segmentation project and copy+pasted some [sample code](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-rc1/dd/d9d/segment_objects_8cpp-example.html) from OpenCV. Unfortunately, when I build it, all dependencies and libraries included, it gives me the following errors:

```
1>Source.cpp
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(void)" (??0VideoCapture@cv@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::~VideoCapture(void)" (??1VideoCapture@cv@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::open(class cv::String const &)" (?open@VideoCapture@cv@@UAE_NABVString@2@@Z) referenced in function _main
1>Source.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual bool __thiscall cv::VideoCapture::isOpened(void)const " (?isOpened@VideoCapture@cv@@UBE_NXZ) referenced in function _main
```

Comment: somehow, you're failing to link opencv_videoio300(d).lib

Comment: YES!! I linked all the libraries except for that one. Thank you! @berak

Answer (score 10, accepted):

link  opencv_videoio300(d).lib

Comment: Same error here. Many thanks.  But I do have to ask, how did you know that the VideoCapture function was tied to that library?  I see the class listed in highgui.hpp, but what is the connection from there to opencv_videoio300d.lib?

Comment: I have added opencv_videoio library but still getting the same error